# C#: how to display the employee names with lowest salary

Tags: c#-4.0

I have to create an appropriate GUI to enter information for at least 10 employee. for each employee i have to enter the following information. employee ID, employee first name, employee last name and yearly salary. besides i have to check for the correctness of the input data. in addition i need to create a separate class **EMPLOYEE**, containing employee information: employee ID, first name , last name and yearly salary. the class should have constructors properties and methods. all the employee information has to be stored in a array of type employee. after reading form GUI the information about particular employee , also create an object of class employee(element of the array) with the relevant constructor. the user would like to be able to find the employee with lowest yearly salary despite of having more than one employee with lowest yearly salary. and display information about them. user should be provided with appropriate GUI to display the required information.
i need to assure including in my program appropriate code for handling exceptions and also methods where appropriate.

here is the class employee:

```
  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Project_employee
{
    class Employee
    {
        private int employeeID;
        private string fullName;
        private string lastName;
        private double salary;
        public Employee()
        {
            employeeID = 0;
            fullName = "";
            lastName = "";
            salary = 0.0;
        }
        public Employee(int empIDValue, string fullNameVal, string lastNameVal)
        {
            employeeID = empIDValue;
            fullName = fullNameVal;
            lastName = lastNameVal;
            salary = 0.0;
        }
        public Employee(int empIDValue, string fullNameVal, string lastNameVal, double salaryValue)
        {
            employeeID = empIDValue;
            fullName = fullNameVal;
            lastName = lastNameVal;
            salary = salaryValue;
        }
        public int EmployeeIDNum
        {
            get
            {
                return employeeID;
            }
            set
            {
                employeeID = value;
            }
        }
        public string FullName
        {
            get
            {
                return fullName;
            }
            set
            {
                fullName = value;

            }
        }
        public int Getinfo
        {
            get
            {
                return employeeID;
            }
            set
            {
                employeeID = value;
            }

        }
        public string employeeInformationToString()
        {
           // employeeID = Convert.ToInt32(this.textBox1.Text);
            return (Convert.ToString(employeeID) + " " + fullName + " " + lastName + " " + Convert.ToString(salary));
        }
    }
}




using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Project_employee
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Searchbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            employee[0] = new Employee();
            employee[1] = new Employee(17433, "Adrian", "Smith", 8000.00);
            employee[2] = new Employee(17434, "Stephen", "Rad", 9000.00);
            employee[3] = new Employee(17435, "Jesse", "Harris", 800.00);
            employee[4] = new Employee(17436, "jonatan", "Morris", 9500.00);
            employee[5] = new Employee(17437, "Morgen", "Freeman", 12000.00);
            employee[6] = new Employee(17438, "Leory", "Gomez", 10200.00);
            employee[7] = new Employee(17439, "Michael", "Brown", 9000.00);
            employee[8] = new Employee(17440, "Andrew", "White", 3500.00);
            employee[9] = new Employee(17441, "Maria", "Carson", 12000.00);
            //employee[10] = new Employee(17442, "Mark", "Jonson", 17000.00);

            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                string employeeString = employee[i].employeeInformationToString() + "\r\n";

                richTextBox1.AppendText(employeeString);

            }

        }
        Employee[] employee = new Employee[10];

        private void getinfibtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Find();
        }
        private void Find()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

## My question is:

How the user can find the employee with the lowest yearly salary. i have to make sure that there can be more than one employee with lowest yearly salary and display the information about them. providing the user with an appropriate GUI (e.g a message box) to display the required information with including appropriate code for handling exceptions and also use methods where appropriate?

Comment: are you want a list of lowest salary employees? if you want this please see my answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your class Employee to implement the **IComparable** interface, then compare the objects against the salary and in the other class sort the array...

## Example:

```
public class Employee :IComparable<Employee>
{
    private int employeeID;
    private string fullName;
    private string lastName;
    private double salary;

  public int CompareTo(Employee other)
  {
     return salary.CompareTo(other.salary);
  }
}
```

---

```
private void Find()
{
    Array.Sort(employee); // after this Employee is sorted
    employee[0];  
    or 
    employee[9];
}
```

Comment: thanks for you help. how can I get specific employee ID full name, last name and yearly salary ?

Comment: Error Name employee doesn't exist in the current context, but it exist Employee[] employee = new Employee[10];

Comment: Yes it is in the find method

Comment: Employee[] employee = new Employee[10]; must be a class variable... I had written employee**s** in the find method, please check if you have that too????

Comment: Now its in the class employee but in the form I have  employee[0] = new Employee();
            employee[1] = new Employee(17433, "Adrian", "Smith", 8000.00);
            employee[2] = new Employee(17434, "Stephen", "Rad", 9000.00);
            and its showing error employee is not exist in the current context

Comment: because I am new to c#

Answer (score 0):

this will give a list of lowest salary emplyees

```
        employee.Add(new Employee(17434, "Stephen", "Rad", 9000.00));
        employee.Add(new Employee(17435, "Jesse", "Harris", 800.00));
        employee.Add(new Employee(17436, "jonatan", "Morris", 9500.00));
        var c = employee.OrderBy(i => i.salary).ToList();
        var e = employee.Where(i => Math.Abs(i.salary - c[0].salary) < 1).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified you code a little bit

```
class Employee
    {
        private int employeeID;
        private string fullName;
        private string lastName;
        private double salary;
        public double Salary
        {
            get
            {
                return salary;
            }
            set
            {
                salary = value;
            }
        }
        //public Employee()
        //{
        //    employeeID = 0;
        //    fullName = "";
        //    lastName = "";
        //    salary = 0.0;
        //}
        //public Employee(int empIDValue, string fullNameVal, string lastNameVal)
        //{
        //    employeeID = empIDValue;
        //    fullName = fullNameVal;
        //    lastName = lastNameVal;
        //    salary = 0.0;
        //}
        public Employee(int empIDValue, string fullNameVal, string lastNameVal, double salaryValue)
        {
            employeeID = empIDValue;
            fullName = fullNameVal;
            lastName = lastNameVal;
            salary = salaryValue;
        }
        public int EmployeeIDNum
        {
            get
            {
                return employeeID;
            }
            set
            {
                employeeID = value;
            }
        }
        public string FullName
        {
            get
            {
                return fullName;
            }
            set
            {
                fullName = value;

            }
        }
        public int Getinfo
        {
            get
            {
                return employeeID;
            }
            set
            {
                employeeID = value;
            }

        }
        public string employeeInformationToString()
        {
            // employeeID = Convert.ToInt32(this.textBox1.Text);
            return (Convert.ToString(employeeID) + " " + fullName + " " + lastName + " " + Convert.ToString(salary));
        }
    }
```

and to get min values in list

```
 var minEmpSalarylist = employee.Where(x => x.Salary == employee.Min(y => y.Salary)).ToList();
```

If default constructor is present then all  `minEmpSalarylist`  become initialized with  **default constructor**.

and

```
employee[0] = new Employee();
```

to change it to

```
employee[0] = new Employee(17433, "XXX", "YYY", 8000.00);
```